# get matched IP addresses from log file

Tags: php

I have an array of IP addresses

```
$ips = ['192.168.1.10',...];
```

and there is a log file on the server **(a very big size file, about 500 MB)**

I want to get any line from log file matched with any ip from the array

Answer (score 2):

If this is one-time event, I would suggest going through the file line by line (`fopen()`, `fgets()` in a loop, `fclose()`) and for each line run a nested loop that checks whether any of the IP addresses is present on the line (`strpos()` will do just fine).

If you are planning to do this repeatedly, I would suggest processing the log and saving it to an engine providing indexing and search capabilities (e. g. database).